# Does tunneling transmission probability depend on the density of states or velocity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, velocity, density, quantum-tunneling

In some quantum text books [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiyTG.png)], the tunneling transmission formula depends only on the density of states of 2 regions (DOS) involved in tunneling. ($T(E) = C \times DOS_1(E) \times DOS_2(E)$, where C is constant). However, in [Landauer transmission formula](http://www.google.com/search?q=landauer+transmission+formula) (without tunneling) the transmission depends on both DOS and velocity of carriers ($T(E) = C' \times DOS(E) \times v$). So I am wondering if velocity is important too? If yes, which velocity in which region?!

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiyTG.png)] For example, see "Introduction to Many-body quantum theory in condensed matter physics", Bruus et al.

[image]

Comment: Why would the first formula involve a product of DOS instead of a ratio? I don't understand what this product is telling us. (note that I assume here the transmission to be say from 1 to 2).

Comment: Because if there is no DOS at each side at one energy, there would not be any tunneling current

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question why the transmission coefficient depend on velocity in a very naive way. Consider a potential barrier like below, the electron is incident from left with energy $E=\hbar^2k^2/2m$, the barrier width is $a$ and height is $V$. Define $\kappa\equiv\sqrt{2m(V-E)/\hbar}$. The transmission coefficient $D$ can be easily calculated:$$D=\frac{4k^2\kappa^2}{(k^2+\kappa^2)^2\sinh^2\kappa a+4k^2\kappa^2}$$

[image]

Making D dimensionless by setting $m=\hbar=a=V=1$, we can plot $D$ vs $E$:

[image]

Since $E=v^2/2$, we can also plot $D$ vs $v$:

[image]

Thus you can see that the coefficient is indeed depend on the velocity, because the damping of the wave function in the barrier will be less when it has a larger energy.